# problem with column separation in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, read.csv

i'm using panda and i have problem with separation. In the csv file the separator is '|'

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:/dane/raport_d.csv',encoding='ansi',low_memory=False,sep='|')
df.head()
```

After executing the code, I only see the headers, not separated by a separator, and the same data
other csv files where the separator is "," I have no problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYssK.png)

Comment: Check that the pipe symbol in your code is exactly the same as in the input file. If in doubt replace all `|` symbols in the input by `\t`

Comment: is the same, I even copied from the csv file "|"

Comment: Are you sure that encoding `ansi` is correct? I can't reproduce the issue with `ascii`, and I get error when I try with `ansi`.

Comment: ancoding isn't a problem, mayby problem is " (double quotes) on both sides |

Nr sprawy SW|"Data deklaracji"|"Data spłaty z deklaracji"|"Kwota deklaracji PLN"|"Operator"|"Operator prowadzący"|"

Comment: Err..., I strongly suspect the original file to have a *strange* format. Could you please open it with notepad (yes, csv files are *text* files) or any other text editor like notepad++ and share here what you get.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the delimiter by tab,

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:/dane/raport_d.csv', sep="\t")
```

and if you get the unicode error,then

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:/dane/raport_d.csv', sep="\t", index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: unfortunately, no changes

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by adding  quotechar="'". But now my dataframe looks
[image]

how to remove all these double quotes?
`data = df.replace('"', '', regex=True`) it's working but still i have double quotes in the headlines

Comment: The commented headers are ok. You have column names with spaces, so imho quotes make sense